# Check for the presence of ID in n+1 timepoint and create a new presence/absence variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I'm sorry if I fail to describe this properly.

Basically I have 3 columns -- Pair, Set1 and Set2.

What I want to know is does Pair appear in either Set1 or Set2 when Gen is equal to Time+1.

So I can then have a 5th variable which is essentially 1 or 0 (yes it's present in the next timepoint, no it is not).

For example, in [this example dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wrd6j2b7tynh4z/df.csv?dl=0) Pair F3 (in Time 1) is not present under either Set when Time = 2.

The only way I can think about doing this is to filter by Time and see if it appears in another time:

```
    time2 <- df %>% 
      filter(Time == 2)
    
    df %>% 
  filter(Time == 1) %>% 
  mutate(Present = ifelse(Pair %in% time2$Set1 | Pair %in% time2$Set2, 1, 0))
```

This works but I'd like to have a more efficient way of looping through each Time point, checking the subsequent time point and then moving forward ...

I don't want to do a for loop within a for loop -- but maybe this is necessary?

---

data

```r
structure(list(Time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Pair = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("F1", "F2", "F3", 
"F4", "F5", "N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5"), class = "factor"), 
    Set1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F5", 
    "F7", "F9", "N1", "N3", "N5", "N7", "N9"), class = "factor"), 
    Set2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L), .Label = c("F10", "F2", "F4", "F6", 
    "F8", "N10", "N2", "N4", "N6", "N8"), class = "factor"), 
    Present = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L
))
```

Comment: You seem to have imported your data poorly - your columns are named A, B, C, D, and the first row has what seems like the actual column names. And all your data are strings--even your numbers have quotes, because the first row are are string column names. Before trying to work with the data you should go back to the import step and import it correctly, possibly setting `header = TRUE` in `read.table()` or maybe needing to `skip` the first row of the file--not really sure. If you need help with that, post it as a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If `odf` is your original data structure, then you can do the following:

1. Melt the `odf` long, adding a new variable which is `Time-1`, putting the `Set1` and `Set2` values into a single column, called `SetValue`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(odf)
df <- melt(odf[,Present:=NULL], id=c("Time", "Pair"),value.name = "SetValue" )[,Time2:=Time-1][]
```

2. Join, this long df on itself, where `Pair=Setvalue` and `Time=Time2`, drop `is.na()` rows, select columns to retain, and ensure uniqueness, then merge back to your original, assigning back to original frame

```
odf = merge(
  odf,
  unique(df[df[,.(SetValue,Time, Time2)], on=.(Pair=SetValue,Time=Time2)][!is.na(Time2), .(Time, Pair,exists=1)]),
  by=c("Time","Pair"), all.x = T
)
```

3. If you like, you can update the NA in your new `exists` column to zero, if this is not the last timepoint

```
odf[Time<max(Time)&is.na(exists), exists:=0][]
```

Output:

```
    Time Pair Set1 Set2 exists
 1:    1   F1   F1   F2      1
 2:    1   F2   F3   F4      1
 3:    1   F3   F5   F6      0
 4:    1   F4   F7   F8      1
 5:    1   F5   F9  F10      1
 6:    1   N1   N1   N2      1
 7:    1   N2   N3   N4      1
 8:    1   N3   N5   N6      1
 9:    1   N4   N7   N8      1
10:    1   N5   N9  N10      1
11:    2   F1   F1   F2      1
12:    2   F2   F2   F4      1
13:    2   F3   F5   F6      1
14:    2   F4   F7   F8      1
15:    2   F5   F9  F10      1
16:    2   N1   N1   N2      1
17:    2   N2   N3   N4      1
18:    2   N3   N5   N6      1
19:    2   N4   N7   N8      1
20:    2   N5   N9  N10      1
21:    3   F1   F1   F2     NA
22:    3   F2   F3   F4     NA
23:    3   F3   F5   F6     NA
24:    3   F4   F7   F8     NA
25:    3   F5   F9  F10     NA
26:    3   N1   N1   N2     NA
27:    3   N2   N3   N4     NA
28:    3   N3   N5   N6     NA
29:    3   N4   N7   N8     NA
30:    3   N5   N9  N10     NA
```

### Updated - Tidyverse option

```
df <- odf %>%
  select(!Present) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Set"),values_to = "SetValue") %>% 
  mutate(Time2= Time-1)

left_join(
  odf %>% select(!Present), 
  inner_join(df, df, by=c("Pair"="SetValue", "Time"="Time2"))  %>% 
    filter(!is.na(Time2)) %>% 
    select(Time, Pair) %>% 
    mutate(exists=1) %>% 
    distinct(),
  by=c("Time", "Pair")
) %>% 
  mutate(exists=if_else(is.na(exists) & Time<max(Time), 0, exists))
```

Comment: thank you for this, but why is Time==3 all NA, when they exist in Time 2?

Comment: Aren't we only checking if it exists in Time+1?  There is no Time=4, so I can't check for existence of the Time=3 rows in Time=4??

Comment: no for every Time, we check if it appears in Time+1

Comment: Okay, but there are no Time=4 rows.. so how can I check if a Time=3 row exists in Time=4?  Sorry, if I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Is it possible you mean for every Time we check it if appears any row where **Time>1** ?. Does that mean you also want to check if it exists in either of the Set columns for its own Time?

Comment: yes, sorry you are correct.

Comment: okay great - does this do it for you then?

Comment: what packages is this using? other than reshape

Comment: just `data.table`

Comment: I've added library(data.table), and `setDT(odf)` and removing the `Present` column (I don't think that column was there previously)

Comment: I've also added a tidyverse option for you, if that is more comfortable